# Mediaelement.js loading wrong format Ffox (MAC)

Tags: macos, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I`m using mediaelement.js library to display videos. The issue is that for Firefox 3.6.13 on MAC the library loads the .mp4 version of the video and not the .ogv version (wich when loaded is displayed properly).My video sources are in the standard order : ".mp4", ".webm", ".ogv". Is it possible to make the browser load the .ogv version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under MAC video acts differently whenever you have QuickTime installed. The MAC would default to playing the QuickTime supported video instead of the HTML 5 format that it supports in this case `OGG`. My suggestion would be to detect platform and to remove the .mp4 source using Modernizr.

```
if (Modernizr.video.ogg) {
    // Remove mp4 source
}
```

[Here is documentation on Modernizr.](http://modernizr.com/docs/)